# getting error while retrieving data from sharepoint online spfx react

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts

Trying to get data from SharePoint online using spfx react ..

> const { siteurl } = this.props;

```
let requestUrl = siteurl.concat(
  "/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Shoping%20CartItems')/items"
);
// Get users with givenName, surname, or displayName
this.context.spHttpClient
  .get(requestUrl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(json => {
    // Prepare the output array

    // Log the result in the console for testing purposes
    console.log(json);
    // Map the JSON response to the output array
    json.value.map((item: any) => {});
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

getting error --

ShopingCart.tsx:65 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at ShopingCart.fetchDatafromSharePointList (ShopingCart.tsx:65)
    at ShopingCart.

Comment: quick question: why do you write your requests manually and don't use instead the fluent API provided by https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/pnpjs/docs/ ?

Comment: Can I use sppnp Js with react ? Or what will be the best practices to fetch data from SharePoint online spfx react .

Comment: react is a UI framework to help you render and display the information on the screen to put it roughly. pnpjs is a fluent API wrapping the REST API. They do not conflict or overlap at all, and combining them for SPFx projects is usually the suggested approach.

Comment: I am having problem while looping ...  getting always extra button . please help .

<div key={myitems1.Id}>
                    <span>{myitems1.Item_x0020_Name}</span>
                    <button onClick={e => this.dosometing(myitems1.Id)}>
                      Offline
                    </button>
                  </div>

Getting always extra and

Answer (score 1):

Even though this doesn't directly answer the question the recommendation would be to leverage [pnpjs](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/pnpjs/docs/) fluent API instead of crafting the requests manually.
This reduced maintenance burden as well as the risk of errors.